# Snakeyml exceptions when running Arquillian Chameleon tests

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian

When running a test using Arquillian Chameleon in Windows, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not setup chameleon container
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering this one myself because it was a simple fix to an odd problem.

I have Windows 10, and was running Maven from the WLS Bash shell. Under bash, Maven worked great and the tests ran as expected. But when I ran the tests in Powershell or from an IDE like IntelliJ, I got that exception.

The solution was to do a `mvn clean`, after which I could run the tests in Windows again. Obviously there is some incompatibility between files created under a Bash shell and those used in a Windows environment, so you can't just swap between the two.

Comment: Thanks, yes probably something related with slashes. Anyway it is always a good practice to do a mvn clean all the time to avoid any unexpected things. Also would you like to improve documentation of the project with this issue you found?

Comment: Work for me ! Same problem on Mac OS X platform using Gradle. Thanks.